# Cloud Firestore not storing user data during firebase auth

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to store user credentials ( name and email ) to cloud Firestore during the time user first signs up for the app.

I am able to create new user but having trouble registering the credentials to Firestore.

Can someone pls tell me what am I doing wrong??

here's the code sample where I am registering user.

```
bool isloggedin = false;
final TextEditingController _email = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _pswd = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _name = TextEditingController();

handleSubmit() {
    if (formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
        setState(() {
            isloggedin = !isloggedin;
        });
        Auth()
            .registerWithEmailAndPassword(
                name: _name.text, email: _email.text, password: _pswd.text)
            .then((value) async {
                await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("users")
                    .doc(value ? .uid)
                    .set({
                        'uid': value ? .uid,
                        'email': _email,
                        'name': _name,
                        'password': _pswd
                    });
            });


        if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
        } else {
            setState(() {
                isloggedin = !isloggedin;
            });
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                        actions: < Widget > [
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: const Text(
                                    'Okay',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                                ))
                        ],
                        title: const Text('Already Registered'),
                            content: const Text(
                                'This Email is already registered with us. Try signing in'),
                    );
                });
        }
    }
}
```

The `handleSubmit()` function is called when a user clicks on create account button .

The user gets registered , but the app does not move forward from this point. But when I press back on my phone, I get to the homepage. So, I know that I've been registered, plus I can see my email on Firebase auth console, but nothing new in the cloud Firestore.

Comment: Do you think that a solution that would write the user data automatically would be useful to you?

Comment: What do u mean? like adding all the user data simueltaneously into the firestore, while creating it?

Comment: Yes, adding user data to Firestore without writing it from the client.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the solution. I've to add the firestore code in firebase.dart file instead of where it was before (signup.dart file), just after the part where i've called the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method of firebaseAuth.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is condition is not awaiting for you call to complete. below code will fix your issue

```
 handleSubmit() {            
    if (formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        isloggedin = !isloggedin;
      });
      Auth()
          .registerWithEmailAndPassword(
              name: _name.text, email: _email.text, password: _pswd.text)
          .then((value) async {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(value?.uid)
            .set({
          'uid': value?.uid,
          'email': _email,
          'name': _name,
          'password': _pswd
        });
       //You need to check condition here like below
       if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isloggedin = !isloggedin;
        });
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Okay',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                      ))
                ],
                title: const Text('Already Registered'),
                content: const Text(
                    'This Email is already registered with us. Try signing in'),
              );
            });
      }
      
      });
    }
    }
  }
```

So, in the code I've moved `if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null)`  exactly after you're adding the data in firestorm and inside `then`.

Comment: thanks , but the issue still remains. The app is stuck, it's not moving forward. user has been registered but the credentials haven't been uploaded to the firestore